# What are the sizes of GDTR, LDTR, IDTR and TR registers?

Tags: x86, nasm, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, gdt

I've searched up on a lot on the net and every time I can only find the sizes of GDT, LDT and IDT.

Here I'm not asking for the size of the table, but I'm asking about the sizes of the **registers**

I know that GDTR is a 64 bit register, but clueless about the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IDTR and GDTR appear to be 10 bytes each.

IDTR can also point anywhere in virtual address space, so obviously its base has to be 64-bit as well.  `lidt` and `lgdt` take the same limit / base structure format, and [the pseudocode](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt) shows that in 64-bit mode they do:

```
                    GDTR(Limit) ← SRC[0:15];
                    GDTR(Base) ← SRC[16:79];
```

The limit (max byte offset) should be considered part of GDTR / IDTR. The [documentation for `sidt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sidt) also says "store IDTR", and what it stores is the same 2 + 8 byte struct that has limit + base.  (The GDTR internally uses the limit to check segment selectors before looking them up in the GDT, so memory within 64k of the address you used with `lgdt` can be used for other things, if it's past the limit.)

It seems `lidt` / `lgdt` don't check for the GDT/IDT base being a canonical address.  The documentation says they `#GP(0)` *If the memory address is in a non-canonical form.* but I think that's talking about the addressing mode to reach the 10-byte memory operand, not the base address.

(If it isn't possible to get a [non-canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716946/why-do-x86-64-systems-have-only-a-48-bit-virtual-address-space) address into the GDTR or IDTR, the CPU could internally store only the significant [48 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509152/why-in-x86-64-the-virtual-address-are-4-bits-shorter-than-physical-48-bits-vs) (or 57 with [PML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_5-level_paging)), bringing the size down to 6 + 2 = 8 bytes.  And do the sign extension back to 64-bit as part of `sidt` / `sgdt`.  But probably it *is* possible to round-trip an arbitrary 64-bit value through GDTR, just make sure the CPU doesn't need to use the GDT for anything before you put in a valid address!)

---

#### LDTR holds a segment selector and a whole descriptor

The documentation for [`lldt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lldt) indicates that if there's no error:

```
    LDTR(SegmentSelector) ← SRC;
    LDTR(SegmentDescriptor) ← GDTSegmentDescriptor;
```

This indicates that the internal LDTR keeps the 16-bit segment selector (the actual operand to `ldtr`, e.g. `ldtr ax`), as well as loading the selected GDT entry and keeping that.  A GDT entry is 8 bytes, but it may decode that entry into some internal format.  (Perhaps not including the type field, which was already checked and required to be of type == LDT)

This implies that like segment registers such as DS or SS, if you change the GDT contents after running `lldt`, the base/limit of the selected entry at the time you ran `lldt` will continue to apply.

#### TR appears similar to LDTR

Again, the documentation shows:

```
TaskRegister(SegmentSelector) ← SRC;
TaskRegister(SegmentDescriptor) ← TSSSegmentDescriptor;
```

As with LDTR, you can only retrieve the segment selector, not the actual descriptor it was storing. [`str r/m16`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/str) and [`sldt r/m16`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sldt) only write a 16-bit destination operand.

But the actual internal register needs to hold onto the whole segment descriptor, not re-index the current GDT with the selector.

Comment: Perfectly understood TR and LDTR, just had one last question about the GDTR and IDTR. If its 10 bytes (80 bits) each, are all 10 bytes accessible while programming? As i understand, and i may be completely wrong, we can only access the 8 bytes of gdtr as you mentioned. So what are the remaining 2 bytes used for? Are they wasted or just not visible?

Comment: @MarcAl: As my answer says, you can get both the base and limit out again with `sidt` or `sgtd`.  This is a total of 2 + 8 = 10 bytes.  So yes, all 10 bytes are accessible in that sense.  Only the low 6 bytes of the base address are truly usable, though, as an actual address.  (Or the low 57 bits with PML5 for 57-bit virtual addresses.)  So yes, the top bits of the base address are effectively useless.  The limit isn't, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check what the CPU manufacturer says, Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3 Chapter 2.4, in sort:
GDT and IDT:

- Base address 32 or 64 bits (in protected and long mode respectively)
- Limit: 16 bits
- Total size: 48 or 80 bits (4+2=6 Bytes or 8+2=10 Bytes)

LDT and TR: 16 bits, as every other segment register.
You can also take a look at wiki.osdev.org, it is a wiki about Operating System development. It has, among others, pages for [GDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT), [IDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/IDT) and [LDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT).